TcpClient connection closes when being inactive
My .NET MAUI application communicates with a server using a tcpconenction. However, if the user turns his phone off or minimizes the application for a few minutes and then reopens it, the connection is closed. I though about checking if the Stream is not null, else opening a new connection, but is there a way to stop NetworkStreams from closing due to inactivity?

TBH there isn't much you can do if the machine is entirely off: the firewall will end the session if there is no data moving. Keepalives only work while the machine is on.

To maintain the connection, you can use a keep-alive mechanism
